# JSF Composite component just works in one page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm having an strange problem. I've created a simple composite component with a method signature:

```
<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="valorBusca" default="" required="true" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <c:attribute name="listenerBusca" required="true" method-signature="void buscarAlgo(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
    <c:facet name="filtrosAdicionais"/>
    <c:facet name="tabela"/>
    <c:facet name="informacoes"/>
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="clearfix.css" target="head"/>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="camposFormulario.css" target="head"/>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="listagem.css" target="head"/>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form tamanho-aba-cadastro clearfix">
    <p:fieldset legend="Filtro" styleClass="clearfix" style="width: 94.5%">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="clearfix">
            <h:outputLabel value="Buscar:"
                           title="Insira a informação a ser buscada."
                           styleClass="hrgi-label-form hrgi-listagem-label" style="padding-right: 8px;"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.valorBusca}"
                         autocomplete="off" immediate="true" style="width:90%"
                         title="Insira a informação a ser buscada.">
                <f:ajax event="keyup" render="tabelaListagem" execute="@this"
                        immediate="true" listener="#{cc.attrs.listenerBusca}"/>
            </p:inputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <c:renderFacet name="filtrosAdicionais" required="false"/>
    </p:fieldset>
    <h:panelGroup id="tabelaListagem" layout="block" class="clearfix"
                  style="width:99%; margin: 1em auto 0 auto;">
        <c:renderFacet name="tabela" required="true"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="painelInformacoes" layout="block" styleClass="clearfix">
        <p:fieldset legend="Informações" style="width: 94.5%">
            <c:renderFacet name="informacoes" required="true"/>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

It wasn't working, so I've updated mojarra to version 2.1.4 in glassfish 3.1.1, but I don't know why, it works in one xhtml file and don't works in another...

In this it works right:

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/popup.xhtml">
<ui:param name="titulo"
          value="#{vendaMsg['popup.adicionar_produto.titulo']}"/>
<ui:param name="popup" value="#{modeloPopupCarregarProduto}"/>
<ui:param name="controladorPopup"
          value="#{controladorPopupCarregarProduto}"/>
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form clearfix">
        <hrgi:listagem listenerBusca="#{controladorPopupCarregarProduto.buscarProdutos}"
                       valorBusca="#{modeloPopupCarregarProduto.valorBusca}">

            .............................

        </hrgi:listagem>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and simply don't work in this:

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/popup.xhtml">
<ui:param name="titulo" value="#{cadastroMsg['popup.cadastro.listagem_produto.titulo']}"/>
<ui:param name="popup" value="#{modeloPopupListagemProduto}"/>
<ui:param name="controladorPopup" value="#{controladorPopupListagemProduto}"/>
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form clearfix">
        <hrgi:listagem listenerBusca="#{controladorPopupListagemProduto.buscarProdutos}"
                       valorBusca="#{modeloPopupListagemProduto.valorBusca}">

                       .................................

        </hrgi:listagem>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

In the second page I receive this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/components/popups/modulo_cadastro/popupListagemProduto.xhtml @18,82 listenerBusca="#{controladorPopupListagemProduto.buscarProdutos}": The class 'com.hrgi.ui.controladores.popups.ControladorPopupListagemProduto' does not have the property 'buscarProdutos'.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:190)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:450)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:453)
at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:935)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at fr.xebia.servlet.filter.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Another strange thing is that in debug mode it enters in the method and when the method finishes this error is thrown!! Here is the method I'm trying to call (is pratically identical to the other that runs correctly):

```
public void buscarProdutos(AjaxBehaviorEvent evento) {
    UIInput input = (UIInput) evento.getComponent();
    String novoValor = (String) input.getValue();
    carregarProdutos(novoValor);
}
```

I did something wrong that I can't see??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buscarProdutos()` method actually threw an exception by itself, however due to a [currently open bug (issue 1806)](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1806) related to invoking actions in composite components, it get swallowed and rethrown as a `PropertyNotFoundException`.

You can find the *real* exception in the debugger and/or by placing the method body inside a `try-catch` and logging it. My bet that it was the `carregarProdutos()` method which threw an exception.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I've found the error... a lot of objects inside that method was this sentence: 
        StringBuilder query=new StringBuilder("SELECT p FROM Produto v WHERE p.descricao like :descricao");
I've changed "v" to "p" and it solved. :)